# Find command question - how to list subdirectories and files under a directory without listing the base directory

Tags: find, aix

Find command - how to list only subdirectories and files  under a directory without listing the base directory, which is passed as a parameter.

Example:

```
find /abc/def/ghi -mtime +10
```

Above command  output is also resulting in base directory being listed along with subdirectory and files inside.

```
/abc/def/ghi 
/abc/def/ghi/fff
/abc/def/ghi/abc.txt
```

I want output to be just as below.

```
/abc/def/ghi/fff
/abc/def/ghi/abc.txt
```

The reason for this question is - `find` command output is being used to remove the directory and files recursively. so if the base directory - `/abc/def/ghi` is not used for 10 days it also gets listed and ultimately gets deleted.

```
find /abc/def/ghi -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: Type `man find` in your terminal and look for the parameter `-mindepth`. You also probably want to have a look at `-type` to select only files and delete them atomically, unless you don't mind [loosing files that where modified (i.e. not added) recentrly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620704/9401096)

Comment: @Zeitounator it's AIX so there's probably no `-mindepth` option (think POSIX rather than GNU)

Answer (score 2):

Look for files that are older than your threshold, and then delete empty directories.

Notice that the `$base` variable is used four times (two in each statement). The `-path "$base/*"` operation ensures that we don't end up deleting `$base` itself - the `*` matches every item anywher in the directory tree other than the topmost `.` or `..`.

```
base=/abc/def
find "$base/" -path "$base/*" -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f {} +
find "$base/" -depth -path "$base/*" -type d -exec rmdir {} + 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This would miss hidden files in `/abc/def/` and would fail if there are extremely many names in that directory (argument list too long). I also couldn't find any documentation saying that `rmdir` is guaranteed to remove _all_ given directories if one of those directories can't be removed (all `rmdir` implementations that I have does that though).

Comment: @Kusalananda answer amended. I believe it's still POSIX and therefore should work on AIX

Answer (score 0):

You can ask `find` to explicitly ignore the top-level search path in two ways.

1. Use the standard `-path` test to avoid acting on the top-level search path:

   ```bsh
   find /abc/def/ghi ! -path /abc/def/ghi ...other tests/actions...
   ```

   This finds the top-level search path, but avoids acting on it since
   it matches the pathname used with the `-path` test exactly.  The `!`
   inverts the sense of a test.
2. Use the non-standard, but commonly implemented `-mindepth` test:

   ```bsh
   find /abc/def/ghi -mindepth 1 ...other tests/actions...
   ```

   This makes `find` ignore all pathnames that lies on "depth zero",
   which is the top-level search paths themselves.
3. A third way, which depends on what it is you actually would want to
   do, is to not be interested in directories (since the top-level search
   paths are usually directory paths):

   ```bsh
   find /abc/def/ghi ! -type d ...other tests/actions...
   ```

Now, looking at what it is that you are wanting to do, it seem as if
you want to clean up directories that haven't had new things added or
deleted from them in the last 10 days.  The safest way to do that would
be to look at *files* specifically, and to delete the files that are
old.  After having done that, you could remove directories that ended up
empty.

The reason you don't want to rely on the timestamps of the directories
is that these timestamps don't say anything about when files in
*subdirectories* were added or deleted.  Deleting a directory because
its timestamp is old, could then accidentally delete fresh files in
lower subdirectories.

I would probably use something like

```bsh
find /abc/def/ghi -type f -mtime +10 -delete
find /abc/def/ghi ! -path /abc/def/ghi -type d -empty -delete
```

The `! -path /abc/def/ghi` could be reoved if you were okay with
deleting the top-level search path if it was empty.

Since the `-empty` test and the `-delete` action are non-standard, the following is how to do the same thing with standard `find`:

```bsh
find /abc/def/ghi -type f -mtime +10 -exec rm -f {} +
find /abc/def/ghi -depth ! -path /abc/def/ghi -type d -exec rmdir {} \; 2>/dev/null
```

The first command should be straight forward.  It collects old files and calls `rm -f` on batches of them.

The second command uses `-depth` to perform a depth-first search.  We do this because

1. We don't want `find` to try to enter directories that we've just deleted, and
2. A directory may *become* empty once we've deleted other directories in it.

The second command also tries to run `rmdir` on *all* directories (apart from the top-level search path).  This will *fail* for non-empty directories, so we redirect the error stream to `/dev/null` to ignore diagnostic messages.

To only call `rmdir` for truly empty directories, we may use

```bsh
find /abc/def/ghi -depth ! -path /abc/def/ghi -type d \
    -exec bash -O dotglob -O nullglob -c '
    for dirpath do
        set -- "$dirpath"/*
        [ "$#" -gt 0 ] && rmdir "$dirpath"
    done' bash {} +
```

This calls a short inline `bash` script that iterates over the directories, and for each directory tries to expand the `*` globbing pattern in it. If it expands to no names at all, the directory is deleted.

Answer (score -5):

nevermind .. got the answer myself with little trial and error.

```
find /abc/def/ghi/* -mtime +10 -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea. You will delete your top-level directories that haven't been changed for 10 (or more) days without regard to the age of the files and directories inside them

Comment: To continue roaimas comment: The modification timestamp on a directory is only updated when a file or directory is created or deleted in it. Your command makes no distinction between subdirectories and their files and will delete directories that nobody added or deleted anything from within 10 days, regardless of whether they contain subdirectories that contain newer files.